# Is it possible to host a bin directory within an MVC application Areas folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appdomain

I have an MVC 4 application that hosts other MVC applications within the Areas folder of the main application:

- Web UI

  - Areas

    - Application 1

      - Content
      - Views
    - Application 2

      - Content
      - Views
  - **Bin**

    - **MainApp.dll**
    - **Application1.dll**
    - **Application2.dll**
  - Config
  - Views
  - Lib
  - Images
  - Other top level application folders

These applications share have their own set of dependencies which all currently reside in the main bin directory. This has caused us issues whereby one application requires a newer version of a package forcing me to upgrade the package within the second application. In my mind a resolution to this would be to isolate the dependencies by having a bin directory within each folder within the Areas folder which could contain the different versions of dependencies:

- Web UI

  - Areas

    - Application 1

      - **Bin**

        - **Application1.dll**
        - **DependencyV1.dll**
      - Content
      - Views
    - Application 2

      - **Bin**

        - **Application2.dll**
        - **DependencyV2.dll**
      - Content
      - Views
  - **Bin**

    - **MainApp.dll**
  - Config
  - Views
  - Lib
  - Images
  - Other top level application folders

Aside from the risks of running multiple versions of dependencies - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want to do.

If you have several apps in your areas, in term of project it's still a single app, so you only have one bin folder.

IIS may allow you to deploy several apps in Virtual directories, but you need to separate your areas (one VS project/csproj per app).

You deploy each app in a different folder, and in IIS you configure the website to the root app, and you right clic on it to add other applications

Comment: Would creating app domains for each plugin be a feasible option?